# Why do we get error saying "train" and "class" have different lengths while using Knn function in R?

Tags: r, variables

I know this question has been asked before, I have checked other portals but didn't get the correct response.

I was doing a school project following a sample manual based on the medical records.

So I begin with splitting the data set into two parts test and train.
There are 569 records and 31 variables :

Wbcd_train : 469 obj. 31 Var.

Wbcd_test : 100 obj. 31 Var.

Wbcd_train_lables : 469 obj. 1 Var.

Adding sample data entries for wbcd_train, wbcd_test, wncd_train_lables.

**wbcd_train** :

**Radius**  17.99 **Texture**  10.38 **Perimeter**  122.8 **Area**  0.1184

**wbcd_test** :

**Radius**  17.6   **Texture**  23.33  **Perimeter**  119  **Area**  980.5

**wncd_train_lables** :

**Diagnosis** M

When using the function :

```
wbcd_test_pred <- knn(train = wbcd_train, test = wbcd_test, cl = wbcd_train_labels, k = 21)
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> knn(train = wbcd_train, test = wbcd_test, cl = wbcd_train_labels,  : 
>   'train' and 'class' have different lengths
> ```

Comment: Post some sample data so we can help you better.

Comment: @earthlink hey man i have added some more data sets please check

Comment: Please do not add your data as images.  No one wants to type it all in.  Instead, please use `dput` to create a text version that we can cut and paste into R. It would be helpful if you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class parameter should be provided as a vector, not as a dataframe. Referring to `Diagnosis` variable in your `wbcd_train_labels` dataframe should work

```
wbcd_test_pred <- knn(train = wbcd_train, test = wbcd_test,
cl = wbcd_train_labels$Diagnosis,...)
```

Comment: Thanks, Oleksii brother the vector worked.So we can infer from this is that whenever we use a function that calls a dataset with one column, we need to call that parameter as a vector.Is this rule valid for all packages in R or specific to class.?

Comment: You are welcome. That purely depends on a particular function in any particular package. Usually, you can find it out from a help page or particular example for the function implementation.